# jQuery input[name=""] selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

So this problem has been driving me insane since yesterday afternoon.  I've been working on a quote calculator for our site, and I'm trying to style the radio buttons on my form.  The quote calculator can be seen here:

http://www.thoughtspacedesigns.com/services/web-services/web-design/web-design-quote-calculator

As you can see, when you click either yes or no on a question, the background changes to an inset orange.  These are simply radio buttons with labels attached to them.  Here's some sample HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="cms" value="yes" id="cms1" /><label for="cms1">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="cms" value="no" id="cms2" /><label for="cms2">No</label>
```

There are multiple "yes / no" radio groups all within the same form.  I then put display:none; on the radio button and styled the labels accordingly.  Then, when a label is clicked, I use jQuery to add a class to it, like so:

```
$("label").live('click', function() {
    var thisInput = $(this).prev("input");
    var radioGroup = thisInput.attr("name");
    $(this).addClass("checked");
    $(":radio[name='"+radioGroup+"']").not(thisInput).next("label").removeClass("checked");
}
);
```

So as you can see, when a radio button's label is clicked, a class of "checked" is added to that label.  This class has styles specified in my stylesheet (namely the background coloring).  Then, all of the radio buttons with the same name that aren't the one that was clicked should have the "checked" class removed.

This works beautifully in FireFox and Chrome, but the minute I try it in IE8 (or IE7), everything works fine, but it seems that the `$(":radio[name='"+radioGroup+"']")` selector is not functioning, as the class isn't being removed.  Essentially, in IE, my labels don't "de-highlight".  I have tried many variations of the selector, using pseudoselectors, filters, and still no luck.  Does anybody have some insight into this?

Comment: `.live` is deprecated, use `.on` instead.

Comment: Does this work in IE9+

Comment: Tried it with .on and still no dice.  I use mac and actually don't hve access to ie9, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IE one of your linked scripts adds the following between the `<label />` and the `<input />` (viewable in developer tools after refreshing the html)

```
<css3-container style="Z-INDEX: -1; POSITION: absolute; DIRECTION: ltr; TOP: 780px; LEFT: 0px">  
    <background style="POSITION: absolute; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 0px">
        <group1>
            <?xml:namespace prefix = css3vml ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" />
            <css3vml:shape style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 86px; HEIGHT: 42px; TOP: 0px; BEHAVIOR: url(#default#VML); LEFT: 0px" coordsize = "172,84" coordorigin = "1,1" fillcolor = "#ff7955" stroked = "f" path = " m0,16 qy16,0 l156,0 qx172,16 l172,68 qy156,84 l16,84 qx0,68 x e">
                <css3vml:fill></css3vml:fill>
            </css3vml:shape>
        </group1>
    </background>
</css3-container>
```

This breaks your selector because `.prev("input")` can't find the input anymore

Comment: BINGO!  The <css3-container> tag was being added in by css3PIE: http://css3pie.com/  PIE is an extension that enables css3 attributes like box shadow in ie7 and ie8.  Apparently it does so by adding an element in before the element it's called on.  To fix my problem, I just removed PIE from the label element.  I still want to use PIE however.  Is there a way to still select this element other than "prev"?  Like maybe "closest"?  I'm not sure.  Opinions?

Comment: @ThoughtSpaceDesigns can't you select by id?  `$('#'+$(this).attr("for"))`

Comment: I would also go with the "for" attribute from the label

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ Using my jQuery, this would select the label for the clicked element, and not the "de-selected" element.  I need to select all radio buttons that aren't selected.

Comment: @ThoughtSpaceDesigns you will need to loop through the other inputs to remove class from the labels - since the structure is inconsistent - Heres how you can do it http://jsfiddle.net/LuhWD/

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ My apologies, that selector does indeed work.  Now I just need to find which selector to use to grab the label element in the last line of my sample js.  Next isn't working either.

Comment: @ThoughtSpaceDesigns Check my fiddle in the previous comment - it shows you how you can grab the labels as I saw that .next() wouldn't work also

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ This Worked!  Thank you so much for your help.  That was quite the handy snippet you came up with.